# Dot product of vectors

Tags: vector, scheme, racket, dot-product

I was wondering how to get the dot product of two vectors.

```
(check-expect (dot (vector 5 1 1) (vector 1 0 0)) (+ 5 0 0))
(check-expect (dot (vector 1 1 5) (vector 1 0 0)) (+ 1 0 0))
```

So essentially I'm trying to build a function (dot) that will satisfy these two check expects.

So far I have only started this by defining the function

```
(define (dot vec1 vec2)
```

I had previously defined a function (vfold) that is the same as foldl except that vfoldl works on vectors rather than lists, but am not sure if I have to use it for this new function.

```
; vfoldl: (X Y --> Y) Y [VectorOf X] --> Y
(define (vfoldl combine base avec)
  (local [(define imax (sub1 (vector-length avec)))
          (define (vaux combine avec index acc)
            (cond [(= index imax) (combine (vector-ref avec imax) acc)]
                  [else (vaux combine
                              avec
                              (add1 index)
                              (combine (vector-ref avec index)
                                       acc))]))]
   (vaux combine avec 0 base)))
```

Comment: Please post a working procedure showing what you've implemented so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the following work? (I don't have an interpreter on hand to test it, give me a minute to check.)

```
(define (dot a b)
    (apply + (vector->list (vector-map * a b)))
)
```

Comment: It won't work (why the `square`?), but something like this will: `(apply + (vector->list (vector-map * v1 v2)))`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I don't know why that was there, I copied a little piece of code but I thought that I had deleted that. Don't know why it popped back up.

Comment: it's fixed now, and that's what matters :) +1

Comment: @ÓscarLópez What makes your version better than this one, is it faster? I don't know racket that well, this is just the way that seemed elegant to me.

Comment: Mine is just ... different. I like yours, it's short and idiomatic. What I like about mine (and this is probably in line with OP's intent) is that it solves the problem directly using vectors, without converting the input to lists.

Comment: It'd probably be better to use `reduce` (or `foldl`, etc.) here than `apply`. Depending on the implementation, a fold mightn't need to convert the intermediate vector to a list, and doesn't run into potential implementation limits regarding number of arguments passed to a function.